# {"message":"Unauthorized"} in API Gateway in Cognito Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I get {"message":"Unauthorized"} error when I add cognito authorizer to my API defined in API Gateway.
I did the following:

1. Configured a Cognito Authorizer
2. Added the Authorizer in API method
3. Deployed the API

As i hit the API url. I get the {"message":"Unauthorized"} error.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you actually authenticating before sending a request to protected API endpoint?

Comment: Depends on how the Authorizer is implemented. You can test it via AWS web console, check if the token you send is valid.

Comment: which token are you using? `access_token` or the `id_token`? If you are using `access_token`, then depending on how your `user pool client` is configured, you may need to add/define scope

Comment: If your api gateway resource has no OAuth scope, the authorizer is waiting for the `id_token`.